# 9x servo on Arduino Nano?

Tags: arduino-nano, servo

I saw this project with multiple servos: [In Servo We Trust! Let's control 135 servos with a single Arduino!](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Maya/in-servo-we-trust-6725f1?ref=search&ref_id=mirror%20panels%20servo&offset=13) I wanted to miniaturize this project.

BUT instead of triangles i will use SQUARES.

:EDIT: summing UP

For now project stops, not forever. I bought 9 servos on aliexpress and im waiting for them to be delivered. Also, im making a 3D project in AutoDesk Maya 2018, planning and will sbow you the results soon how im gonna make it work. 
I was thinking about adding 1 more servo and hc sr06 distance sensor. I was thinking about the sensor will detect person, servos and mirrors will also follow the person. But idk if im gonna make it to the final project.

- I bought arduino nano that will be powered from the battery
- All servos will be powered with electricity from the wall 5V 5A.The servos wont be on heavy load so it will be enough i think.If any problem occurs I will use 10A.

ALSO SORRY for not editing this POST earlier.

I would like to thank everybody for giving me such a great advices, I will post my AutoDesk project soon.

[image: Fritzing Diagram]

Answer (score 2):

> I'm afraid that with PWM controler I won't be able to do that.

Chances are that any PWM controller is going to let you control each output independently.

According the the [servo](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/servo) library documentation, the library can handle up to 12 servos on a single Arduino, so your project should be feasible. It will however reduce the number of PWM pins available from 6 down to 4.

> Will a 9V battery power all these servos?

No! Not a chance.

Typical 9g servos consume 150 mA without any load, and stall at ~700-900 mA. A typical 9v has ~500 mAh capacity, and most data sheets show loads of ~100-150 mA max. Your 9v might be able to supply a few amps for a few seconds before they heat up and slow down.

If your load is very light 9 servos will consume ~900 mA; an ideal 9v would last at most 30 min with this load, but real batteries aren't ideal and will heat up and loose efficiency.

Near maximum load your 9 servos will draw ~7000-9000 mA, well beyond the capabilities of a 9v. However those numbers are for 5v so you could cut them all in half.

If you used an appropriate 5v step-down DC-DC supply you might be able to power all 9 servos for a few seconds before the batter overheats and gives up.

If you powered them directly, the servos will have to dissipate more heat, and will draw extra power, could damage the servos if the batter could supply enough juice.

Comment: Yes, I know. But i need only 9 servos and PWM controller can operate on 16. From this forum: http://rcarduino.blogspot.com/2012/04/servo-problems-with-arduino-part-1.html, I know that i need separetly battery to power arduino and servos. Let me do a schematic of what im thinking. I'll post it in a minutes.

Comment: Here's the photo. In nano there's 10 digit pins. I'll take 9 and control each servo separately. Will it be fine? What about the voltage to power the servos? 9V battery will do?

Comment: @LazyArtistSQuex 9g servos don't take much power; a 9v should power at least one, but I don't know about trying to power 9 at once with a single 9v, n.b. the operating voltage of most 9g servos is 4-6v

Comment: If the servo operates on 4-6V, doesn't 9V will be too much for a single one? How about I buy this only to power 9 servos? https://pl.aliexpress.com/item/1pc-3S-11-1V-1500mAh-35C-Lipo-Battery-XT60-T-Plug-for-RC-Car-WLtoys-V950/32827187894.html?spm=a2g0s.13010208.99999999.293.110d3c006Q80BG. I've read that one servo takes 500mA. So for 9 will me 4,5A. I can not find information how many amps this battery provides.

Comment: @LazyArtistSQuex it's not the voltage that's the problem, its the capacity. The battery you linked claims to be 35C, so 1.5 aH * 35C = 52.5 A max discharge, which would drain that batter in under 2 min; If the specs claimed are accurate.

Comment: Now i understand. Sorry, it's 3 a.m. and i've been thinking of this for nearly 3h.
So it's not all about the voltage. I can use 5V battery but i need higher capacity. If i use 10'000 mAh the servos will drain it in about 13 minutes. It's okay but battery like this costs around 20$.
Another option might be power directly from the electricity from the outlet. Of course i suppose I'll need voltage converter from 230V to 5V. Will this work?

Comment: @LazyArtistSQuex a 10 Ah batter will run a 10A load for an hour, that would only occur under the heaviest load for your servos stall==maximum load; under a light load, a 10 Ah Battery could last 10 hours or longer for 9 servos @ ~ 1 A total, so it totally depends on the load the servos will experience; yes wall power will work you will need a power supply, of course

Comment: Okay. So let's make things clear. I don't need PWM servo controller, i can only use arduino nano for 9 servos.
Power problem:
I power arduino nano with the battery. I power servos with the wall electricity, but i need voltage converter from 230V to 5V and it needs to be at least 9-10A. The servos will not be on heavy load. Just small turns like on the video from the project.

Comment: @LazyArtistSQuex for a light load you can get away with less than 10A, 5A may suffice for a light load, 2A for a very light load.

Comment: Or use two 5A supplies. Couple like these  http://www.mpja.com/5-Volt-DC-Plug-Power-Supply-4A-Regulated/productinfo/18520+PS

Comment: @CrossRoads just out of curiosity how am I gonna connect TWO of this cables (how to plug in them). I was thinking about this: https://www.shemeck.pl/851-rs-25-5-zasilacz-impulsowy-25w-5v-5a.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwnNvaBRCmARIsAOfZq-0V5hE3NSN0M3dAXipw7TWMhuBYspNMe47AFRVXle7X0Jt_RA42adUaAthOEALw_wcB as a power for servos.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the specifications of the SG90 (from [FEETECH (Fitec) FS90 9G Mini Servo with Accessories](https://www.addicore.com/FS90-Mini-Servo-p/113.htm))

> [image: SG90 specifications]

The FG90 is similar in specification to the SG90. From the website:

> The FS90 is a 9 g analog servo from FEETECH (formerly known as Fitec) which is similar in form and function to the Towerpro SG90. The specifications state that this servo has a 120° operating angle for standard servo pulses between 900 µs and 2100 µs. As with most servos, the pulse range can be expanded to achieve an expanded operating angle, but the limits of which are not specified by FEETECH.

From [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246642/power-supply-circuit-for-powering-sg90-servo-how-to-handle-high-current-require#answer-339548) to [Power supply circuit for powering SG90 servo. How to handle high current requirements?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246642/power-supply-circuit-for-powering-sg90-servo-how-to-handle-high-current-require), lets assume each servo (best case) needs 250 mA, as you state that the load per servo is relatively low.

Let's say that the Nano requires 280 mA, see [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/926/what-is-the-maximum-power-consumption-of-the-arduino-nano-3-0#answer-932) to [What is the maximum power consumption of the Arduino Nano 3.0?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/926/what-is-the-maximum-power-consumption-of-the-arduino-nano-3-0)

Using a single 5V supply to power both servos and Arduino. The current rating needs to need at least:

```
I = (9 x 0.25) + 0.28
I = 2.53 A
```

Or power rated

```
P = I x V = 2.53 x 5
P = 12.65 W
```

You probably want more than that, so get a 5 V 5 A supply to be on the safe side. So, no, a battery will not suffice.

Comment: I wanted to make separetly power for nano and servos, but this way will work too.

Comment: I wanted to buy these: https://pl.aliexpress.com/store/product/4pcs-PKCELL-1-2V-4-5A-2100mAh-NiMh-Rechargeable-Batteries-Flat-Top-For-Soldering/918700_32822951027.html?spm=a2g17.search0104.3.44.7b6621e1Ks4oz8&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_10342_10343_10340_10341_10696_10084_10083_10618_10304_10307_10820_10821_10301_10843_10059_100031_10103_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620,searchweb201603_13,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=774f7647-2d15-445d-af5c-46e6fb9b3e5a-6&algo_pvid=774f7647-2d15-445d-af5c-46e6fb9b3e5a&priceBeautifyAB=0.

Comment: 4*1,2V=4,8V and 8400mAh and 5A. Will it be enough?

Comment: Or poeer from the wall and converter from 230V to 5V and 5A. This seems like a cheaper option and more reliable. It costs like 7$. So can i use this power to the arduino nano and power sergos from the Vin pin 5V? The 5A wont be to much for arduino nano? If not ill use just ppwer from the battery to the nano and servos will be povered from the wall

Comment: @LazyArtistSQuex you can power them separately (with sufficient power supplies) but you must connect the ground lines together (only the ground) to ensure everything has the same reference for the voltage.

Comment: @LazyArtistSQuex: Nano runs off 5V. The Nano will draw as much current as it requires, so you could use a 5 V 20 A supply and the Nano will be fine. The supply does not *force* the current into the Nano (or any device), the device pulls what is needed from the supply (and no more). Only the voltage of the supply has to match (and **not exceed**) the (maximum) voltage requirements of a device (i.e. the Nano). The supply only has to *provide* the **minimum required current**, in order for the device to operate correctly but it can provide more and the device will not break. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems more clear now. I edited my post;))

Answer (score 1):

You can drive upto 20 servos on an Arduino Nano - here's the EXCELLENT software for this: http://www.lamja.com/?p=504

Most servos can run well using high voltages (e.g. 9v) while still accepting PWM signals much lower (e.g. 3.3v) - here's a video showing that working fine:  https://youtu.be/9ZCiQgjcx3k

See Greenonline's answer table (or servo datasheets) to work out your power budget.  9v will work, but is probably more than the servos would like: 6v is more usual.

Answer (score 0):

Cheapest way is that you should buy couple of LM7805 wire it in parallel now power arduino and other servos from this 7805. Connect pwm pins of servos to the nano.

Voltage regulator built inside arduino cant provide much current to all servos.

Also connect ground of all of your power sources together.

Answer (score 0):

Servos don't use PWM, not really. What they need is a pulse that is ~ 1mS wide every 20mS (50 Hz) to turn full one direction, ~ 1.5mS wide to be centered, and about 2mS wide to turn fully the other direction.  Or centered, +/- ~ 60-75 degrees or so.

(0.9mS to 2.1mS per the data above).

Comment: So, what you are telling me I won't be able to connect 9 servos directly to arduino nano? https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&biw=1366&bih=673&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=JX1XW-u8OdGWsAejsZW4Cg&q=arduino+nano+pwm&oq=arduino+nano+pwm&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i30k1l7j0i8i30k1.8231.8911.0.9245.4.4.0.0.0.0.333.566.2-1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.img..2.2.565...0i67k1.0.yGDezZalT9M#imgrc=Et2rxIh3mJeo-M:

Comment: The Servo.h library will control up to 12 servos on a 328P based board, such as the Nano. But it's not using PWM to do to it.  You will need a decent power supply to power them if you plan on moving 9 at once for any length of time.  Perhaps two or three of something like this http://www.mpja.com/5-Volt-DC-Plug-Power-Supply-4A-Regulated/productinfo/18520+PS/ and don't forget power connectors http://www.mpja.com/55_21mm-Power-Jack-Screw-Terminals/productinfo/19454+PL  Be sure to connect all Gnds together.

Comment: Thanks for the power supply answer. So arduino nano will be suitable for my project or use another board?

Comment: 12 > 9, so yes, it will suitable.

Comment: Great, now i need the parts to come. Also i need to design the case that will hold all components (i will make it from wood). Will update in short time. Thanks Sir.